# Unwrap HibernateConstraintValidatorContext not working

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I use

- Hibernate validator 5.1.1.Final
- Validation api 1.1.0.Final

  ```
  public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {


  if(value.toString().isEmpty()){
      HibernateConstraintValidatorContext hibernateContext =
              context.unwrap(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class );

      ...........
                  ...........
  }

     return true;
  }
  ```

Above code throw ValidationException, apidoc say "If the Bean Validation provider implementation does not support the specified class, ValidationException is thrown."

**Exception**

```
     [2014-06-12T11:44:05.295+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] []                                    [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1402566245295] [levelValue: 800] [[
       javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
         javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:284)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:133)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validatePropertyForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:855)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validatePropertyForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:768)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateValueInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:725)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateValue(ValidatorImpl.java:184)
at javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.validate(BeanValidator.java:306)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1165)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:983)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:552)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:399)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:263)
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1193)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.invokePhase(FlowLifecycle.java:91)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.execute(FlowLifecycle.java:69)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.processUserEvent(JsfView.java:115)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:225)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:195)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:537)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:228)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:57)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:79)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:66)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
        Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000036: Type interface org.hibernate.validator.constraintvalidation.HibernateConstraintValidatorContext not supported for unwrapping.
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorContextImpl.unwrap(ConstraintValidatorContextImpl.java:83)
at es.project.validator.jsr.NotEmptyValidator.isValid(NotEmptyValidator.java:20)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:281)
... 100 more
```

So I need change/add any jar?

Comment: Can you share the exact exception (stacktrace) you get?

Comment: @Gunnar, question is edited with trace. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give some more context? Where do you run Bean Validation. Looks like you are using Glassfish. Are you trying to bundle your own HV and BV jars on top of the provided Bean Validation implementation provided by Glassfish? Are you able to test your custom constraint implementation standalone? Does that work?

Comment: Hi @Hardy, my custom constraint works fine, problem was HibernateConstraintValidatorContext class which is on 5.1.1 version and Glassfish provide old version for this jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you have several versions of Hibernate Validator on your classpath. This causes `HibernateConstraintValidatorContext` to be loaded twice through different class loaders, resulting in the exception in `unwrap()`.

Do you have by any chance added Hibernate Validator as dependency to your deployment (WAR, EAR etc.)? If so, this may the cause as you obtain the `HibernateConstraintValidatorContext` class from your packaged HV library, whereas the container/JSF uses the one coming with GlassFish. In this case you should remove the HV version you add to your deployment. If the one provided by GlassFish is too old, you should look into updating it (there has been a question on how to do this recently here on SO).

Comment: You were right @Gunnar, Glassfish provide a old HV version in this case. Could you say me how you discover this issue? Cheers.

Comment: The message "HibernateConstraintValidatorContext not supported for unwrapping" indicated that two HV versions must be involved (otherwise the unwrapping should succeed). Glad to hear I could help :)